# Unable to create an Azure Cloud Service in C# with VS2013/2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-sdk

It all - probably - started because I installed Azure SDK .NET 2.9 to begin with, whereas my company's projects are still based on 2.7. When I installed 2.7, the project creation was failing because of an incompatibility between 2.7 and 2.9. I followed the steps advised on stackoverflow.

My issue is the following one: I added a Web Role into a new Azure Cloud Service template:

```
The following NuGet packages could not be installed in project Slip:

Microsfot.WindowsAzure.Caching (version 'unknown'): Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
WindowsAzure.Storage (version 'unknown'): Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
```

If I click on Ok, it then says:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version 5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken-...' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I can then still add the dependency manually and try to start the web role locally but it says:

```
Failed to locate the Microsoft Azure SDK. Please make sure the Microsoft Azure SDK v2.7 is installed.
```

The SDK is there otherwise I could not have created the project in the first place, but maybe a part is missing ?

I tried both with VS 2013 and 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I was not carefully following the "Install Instructions" from Microsoft website where you can download the SDK.